# How to join two utf8 strings together in Clarity?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, clarity, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

In my Clarity smart contract, I am trying to to append one string ("Hello") to another string (" to Clarity Language"). Both strings are of type `string-utf8`.

Deploying the contract below fails with an error: `expecting expression of type \'(string-utf8 100)\', found \'(string-utf8 120)\'`

```
(define-data-var a-string (string-utf8 100) u"Hello")

(var-set a-string (concat (var-get a-string) u" to Clarity Language"))
(print (var-get a-string))
```

How to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

`concat` does not optimize the resulting string. The new string is of type string-utf8 with length 120, adding the length of the variable type to the length of the other string (100 + 20).

You have to wrap the `concat` call with a `as-max-len?`:

```
(define-data-var a-string (string-utf8 100) u"Hello")

(var-set a-string 
  (unwrap! (as-max-len? 
    (concat (var-get a-string) u" to Clarity Language") u100) (err "text too long")))
(print (var-get a-string))
```

Note, that the type length is defined by an `int` (`100`), while `as-max-len?` takes a `uint` parameter (`u100`).